# Python how to vectorize this loop that perform assignment of a sub-rectangle inside an image

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I have 2 arrays: `bot` and `top`, and an `image`. I need to loop over the array, and for each pair of `(bot,top)`,I need to fill column `3 * i + 1` from rows `bot[i]` to `top[i]` with 255.

I want to use vectorized code instead of a for loop to make it faster. I've tried some array indexing, but I don't know the correct syntax.

How should I change the code below?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 100
image = np.zeros((32, 32))

np.random.seed(42)

data = {
    'Bot': np.array([2, 5, 3, 1, 7], dtype=np.int32),
    'Top': np.array([3, 6, 4, 2, 10], dtype=np.int32)
}

# I don't have access to data, just df
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

value = 255
for i in range(len(data)):
    image[df.loc[i]['Bot'] : df.loc[i]['Top'] + 1, 3 * i + 1] = value

image2 = np.zeros((32, 32))
image2[df['Bot'] : df['Top'] + 1, np.arange(len(df)) * 3 + 1] = value # error on this line

print(image == image2)
```

Running the code above, I have this error

```
ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
import numpy as np

image = np.zeros((32, 32))

bot = np.array([2, 5, 3, 1, 7], dtype=np.int32),
top = np.array([3, 6, 4, 2, 10], dtype=np.int32)

value = 255

top2 = 3 * top + 1
dim1 = [list(range(z[0], z[1])) for z in zip(top, top2)]
repeat = [len(itm) for itm in dim1]
dim1 = [itm for sublist in dim1 for itm in sublist]
dim0 = np.repeat(bot, repeat)
image[dim0, dim1] = value
```

I'm not 100% about the indexing precision. You may have to add a -1/+1 somewhere. Like maybe:

```
dim1 = [list(range(z[0]+1, z[1])) for z in zip(top, top2)]
```

Answer (score -1):

i asked chatgpt and he fixed the line

```
image2[df['Bot'].values: df['Top'].values + 1, np.arange(len(df)) * 3 + 1] = value  # Fixed this line
```

heres complete code btw

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 100
image = np.zeros((32, 32))

np.random.seed(42)

data = {
    'Bot': np.array([2, 5, 3, 1, 7], dtype=np.int32),
    'Top': np.array([3, 6, 4, 2, 10], dtype=np.int32)
}

# I don't have access to data, just df
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

value = 255
for i in range(len(data)):
    image[df.loc[i]['Bot']: df.loc[i]['Top'] + 1, 3 * i + 1] = value

image2 = np.zeros((32, 32))
image2[df['Bot'].values: df['Top'].values + 1, np.arange(len(df)) * 3 + 1] = value  # Fixed this line

print(np.array_equal(image, image2))
```

Comment: Have you tested it? Or taken a few minutes to wonder if that line of code made any sense?

Comment: ... Did you even run the code? It shows `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`